# SQL list Name within a group

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Name num1 num2 num3

A    1 2 3

B    1 2 3

C    2 2 3

D    2 5 3
```

I want to collect tha (unique) Name, when all of their other properties (num1, num2, num3) are the same and there are more than one names in that group.

So for this example I would like to get something like

```
A 1 2 3

B 1 2 3
```

My idea was to make a 'group by num1,num2,num3' but this way I cannot reach to list the names, only the count(*) of the groups (how many members they have).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list the original records, then use `group by` and a `join`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select num1, num2, num3 
      from table t
      group by num1, num2, num3
      having count(*) > 1
     ) dups
     on t.num1 = dups.num1 and t.num2 = dups.num2 and t.num3 = dups.num3;
```

If you want to just get the list of names, many databases offer an ability to concatenate strings.  For example, in MySQL you can do:

```
select num1, num2, num3, group_concat(name) as names
from table t
group by num1, num2, num3
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM the_following_table t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM the_following_table x
  WHERE x.num1 = t.num1 AND x.num2 = t.num2 and x.num3 = t.num3
  AND x.name <> t.name
  );
```

Should I explain this? the above query says: "give me all records from the following tables for which another record exists, with exactly the same values for num[123] , but with a different name"